# Unit circle in taxi-cab, Euclidean and Chebyshev distance visualized

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Given the taxi-cab $$t(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i - y_i|$$ Euclidean $$e(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - y_i)^2}$$ and Chebyshev metric $$c(x,y) = max_{i}^{n}\{{|x_i - y_i|\}}$$ how can they be visualized in terms of the unit circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following plots a selection of uniformly distributed points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The evaluation of whether or not a point is contained in the unit circle is indicated by red (true) or blue (false).

[image: taxi-cab]

[image: euclidean]

[image: chebyshev]